# Is CamelGroovyMethods used as a groovy category?

Tags: dynamic, groovy, apache-camel, decorator

Apache Camel comes with some relatively nice Groovy extensions so that you, for instance, can use closures with the Java DSL for defining routes.

Most, if not all, of the additional methods providing these extensions seem to be located in the class `CamelGroovyMethods` with static methods like

```
public static ProcessorDefinition<?> process(ProcessorDefinition<?> self,
        Closure<?> processorLogic){/* implementation */}
```

How is the actual extension of the Camel java classes realised? Is `CamelGroovyMethods` used as a category somewhere, and if so, where is `use(CamelGroovyMethods`) called?

Comment: It's probably added in the same way as methods from `DefaultGroovyMethods`, via meta programming and Meta Object Protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but as they are called extension methods they have probably been defined as such. Look in the jar, you should find a file called org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule in META-INF/services. Have a look at [Creating an extension module](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+an+extension+module). I've used this technique myself and it works great except if you want to provide custom constructors, that requires an alternate mechanism.

...
Yep, found it [ExtensionModule file in GitHub](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-groovy/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule). They even provided the dsld file to assist with code completion in Eclipse.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you very much for the article link, it'll help me understand it a bit better!